# How do I setup a jndi datasource in glassfish 3.1?

Tags: glassfish, datasource, jndi

I need to setup jndi datasource in my web application deployed on the glassfish server. I don't want to use glassfish admin console for creating connection pool and jndi datasource. (This works though.)

I would want to use some xml files like context.xml (used in tomcat) to specify the jndi datasource details which will be bundled with the application war file.

This way if I deploy my app war file I would not have to do any changes in the glassfish from the admin console.

Please help.

PS. I tried putting context.xml in war META-INF, but its not working. When I deploy my war on glassfish it says jndi name not found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't set up resources on Glassfish application server from within an enterprise application; I would even say it's true for any Java EE-compliant application server. It's simply against EJB separation of roles: preparing the application is the role of *Enterprise Bean Provider* and *Application Assembler*, and installing it on the server belongs to the *Deployer* (see [EJB 3.1 spec](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/ejb-3.1-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/ejb-3_1-fr-spec.pdf), chapter 2.2).

You surely don't have to set up everything manually, though. Glassfish has a command line tool `asadmin`, with the help of which you can script all operations accessible from the GUI admin console — take a look at the [Glassfish Admin Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2416/gcode.html#scrolltoc).